# Unable to create Bootable Installer for macOS Sierra 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException' error

Tags: macos, terminal, bootable

I have tried to create a bootable installer for macOS Sierra to use on my MacBook Air that is broken and needs to reinstall macOS (The macOS X Lion installer that comes with the Macbook is broken and says it is unable to install additional components needed to install macOS).

I have tried to follow these instructions; https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 but they haven't worked.

I used this code in the terminal:
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Backup --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app

(The drive I am trying to use is called 'Backup'﻿ and has been erased to become a 'macOS Extended (Journaled)' type drive.)
After entering my password and waiting for about two minutes I receive this error:

"2019-11-05 11:07:18.778 createinstallmedia[21078:275343]

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 35'

*** First throw call stack:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff360dcf53 __exceptionPreprocess + 250

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6c1ac835 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   Foundation                          0x00007fff38715fd5 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 5014

3   Foundation                          0x00007fff387235a5 +[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:] + 153

4   createinstallmedia                  0x00000001087f2968 createinstallmedia + 6504

5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6d50f2e5 start + 1
```

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

It is expected to look more like:
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macos/macos-high-sierra-terminal-create-bootable-installer.png

Comment: I have come across with same issue, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @nadim Unfortunately I have not found a solution for the issue yet but I am still looking.

Comment: Having the exact same issue.

Comment: Anyone manage to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I am using a 2017 MacBook Pro with Catalina, and the solution is a combination of a similar resolved issue on iFixIt forums and using unofficial downloads of the macOS Sierra DMG file.

1. Download the DMG for Sierra here: https://themacgo.com/macos-sierra-10-12-6-dmg-mac-free-download/
2. Mount the DMG file, and copy the `Installer macOS Sierra.app` file to `/Application`
3. Open `Terminal` and write `sudo su`, and enter your password when asked.
4. Run the command `/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/[YOUR VOLUME]/ --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/` (Replace **[YOUR VOLUME]** with your actual volume.
5. Press `Y` to confirm when asked to format the volume.

You will run into an issue during installation when the installer will say it is damaged. A simple hack worked for me, thanks to [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57aA8e9YQSg). Simply do the following:

1. In the menu, select `Utilities` and then `Terminal`.
2. Set the date back in time when the installer should be working. I just randomly picked a date two years back: `date 0416218002018`. The format is `date MMDDhhmmYYYY`.
3. Run the installation and it works!

Comment: It worked for me!
On my late 2011 MacBook Pro, I had to set `date 041618002012` before it allows me to install

Answer (score 13):

This works for me, I found it in an Apple forum:

With Install macOS Sierra.app in the Applications folder open Terminal and copy and paste this
 
 sudo plutil -replace CFBundleShortVersionString -string "12.6.03" /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Info.plist
 
press Return
enter your password
press Return
 
now enter the createinstallmedia command for Sierra in Terminal (MyVolume is Apples default name for a USB but you can enter the name of your USB in there.
 
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app 
 
press Return and follow the prompts.

Comment: It worked. Do you happen to know what the solution does, and why it is needed? Thanks